# Append missing values to CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I have a sorted CSV file in following format-

```
X,Y
0,0
0,1
0,2
1,0
1,1
2,0
2,1
2,1
```

Here, a value `1,2` is absent. This is just a sample, my file contains a 1 million records with a few thousand absent. How can I write a script to detect and append these values to the file?

I have tried generating all possible pairs and check if they are present in the file or not, but is way too slow-

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv') as csvfile:
r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for row in r:

    for i in range(1000):
        for j in range(1000):
            if (int(row[0]) == i and int(row[1]) == j):
                # Can perform operations here
```

Is there some way I can use Numpy or Pandas (I'm very new to those) to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it for some academic reasons? Otherwise why dont you just generate all possible pairs and write it to the file rather than check for missing?

Comment: Actually, there is an additional column with a count value for each record.

Answer (score 3):

One way using sets:

```
from intertools import product
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')

set(product(df1.X.unique(), df1.Y.unique())).difference(set((i[1], i[2]) for i in df1.itertuples()))
```

Output:

```
{(1, 2), (2, 2)}
```

Comment: My answer wasn't tested. Thanks for checking it out. (Deleted)

Comment: @amadispstac if this solution helped you would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) it.

Comment: The notification came to me. Best to comment under the question.